# What kind of exponential functions don't have primes?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Consider $2y^x-1$; for what $y$ does this function's range not contain a prime? Having $x>0, y>1$.

Comment: Do you mean that there is not a prime in the range of the function? Also, "like when we have" is not very precise (I removed it). If you want to consider more general functions you'll have to write it down properly

Comment: @Ant I mean that for any integer x and a constant y, there are no primes in the function, like 2*3^x-1 function.

Comment: The phrase "there are no primes in the function" does not make sense. A function does not contain numbers. So, are you referring to the range of that function?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Sorry for the bad english, that is exactly what I meant.

Comment: @Ant exactly. Sorry for bad english.

Comment: @MyName Based on your comment, I've edited the question; if I edited incorrectly feel free to undo.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I think that is what I meant.

Comment: I think this is a very good question, and I have no idea what the answer is. Note that this can be rephrased (essentially) as: suppose I have a linear function $f(x)=ax+b$ with $a, b$ integers, $a$ positive, and a starting value $c$. Let $c_1=c$, $c_{n+1}=f(c_n)$. For what $a, b, c$ do we have $c_i$ composite for all $i$? For example, in the case you mention in the OP, we have $c=2y-1$, $a=y$, and $b=y-1$. Googling around I can't find anything about iterated linear systems missing primes - there are too many hits related to primes in arithmetic sequences etc. instead, which aren't relevant.

Comment: Heuristically one expects that every such sequence will eventually contain a prime: because the prime density decreases as $1/\log N$, and the size of the $n$-th term increases exponentially, the sum of the densities diverges (slowly).

Comment: @NoahSchweber there is obvious ones like $f(x) = 3^x + 1, c=1$ where all of the outcomes are even. But for this particular function I can't think of any.

Comment: That being said, the terms become large very quickly (for $y=19$, say), and so it may be hard to find the first prime in any particular sequence.

Comment: @mjqxxxx Yes, computerized testing is not easy for this one.

Comment: See https://oeis.org/A119591 (which cites a conjecture that the range *always* contains a prime).

Comment: @BarryCipra I did not know that...